# How can I std::copy a string to a struct with the std::string fields

Tags: c++, string, c++11, struct, std

I read from a file lots of records into a std::vector like this:

```
std::fstream in("storage.txt", std::ios::in);
stxxl::vector<Citizen> v;
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<Citizen>(in), std::istream_iterator<Citizen>(), std::back_inserter(v));
```

The struct `Citizen` is defined as:

```
struct Citizen
{
    std::string firstname, lastname;
    int year;
};
```

That function is created for the `isteam_iterator`:

```
std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& i, Citizen& c)
{
    i >> c.firstname >> c.lastname >> c.year;
    return i;
}
```

During creation of the first struct I get a segmentation fault. Why? I know, the struct's string fields have not enough space. Changing the type to `char fieldname[some size]` solves the problem, but it is a C style and I don't want to use it.

How can I allocate space for that example?

Comment: There's no need to allocate space, `>>` will resize the string correctly. The problem is somewhere else. Do you get the same problem with `std::vector`? Can you reduce the problem to a [minimal but complete test case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Have you used your debugger to see exactly what causes the segfault?

Answer (score 4):

You're not actually using `std::vector` here:

```
stxxl::vector<Citizen> v;
```

As it says in the [STXXL FAQ](http://algo2.iti.kit.edu/dementiev/stxxl/trunk/FAQ.html), `stxxl::vector` can only be parametrized with POD types. `std::string` is not a POD type, nor is any struct that has it as a member.

If you have no good reason to use `stxxl::vector`, use `std::vector`. Otherwise, you're restricted to POD types, which can mean C-style strings of fixed maximum size.